# Why is there extra space created in this flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I was just wondering why there is extra space created in this code. I did not change the flex-grow. This is the code:

```
<body class=picHome>
    <div class=header>
            <div>
                <img src="Pics/example.jpg" alt="EXAMPLE IMAGE" style="width: 10%;"> Example Website 
            </div>
      <button type="button" class="button1" onclick="window.location.href = ''">a</button>
            <button type="button" class="button2" onclick="window.location.href = ''">b</button>
            <button type="button" class="button3" onclick="window.location.href = ''">c</button>
            <button type="button" class="button4" onclick="window.location.href = ''">d</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and my stylesheet:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.picHome {
  background-image: url("");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
}
button {
  text-decoration: none;
}
button:hover {

}
```

Thanks! Please help with this I've been stuck for a while and think it has to do with putting two things in one div.

Comment: What extra space exactly?

Comment: It's the header on this page:         http://pointborohs.org/!Matt/ExWeb1/

Comment: Space where top, bottom, between buttons?

Comment: Between the title and first button

Comment: So want the buttons which are on right should come toward left to make space lesser?

Comment: yes that is correct